# Closed form for $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\,\cdot\,\operatorname{Ci}x-\cos x\,\cdot\,\operatorname{Si}x}{\sqrt{16\,x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Is it possible to find a closed form for this integral?
$$\mathcal{S}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\cdot\operatorname{Ci}x-\cos x\cdot\operatorname{Si}x}{\sqrt{16\,x^2+1}}dx,$$
where $\operatorname{Ci}x$ is the [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) and $\operatorname{Si}x$ is the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html):
$$\operatorname{Ci}x=-\int_x^\infty\frac{\cos t}t dt,\ \operatorname{Si}x=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}t dt.$$
Numerical integration gives
$$\mathcal{S}\approx0.133456902778362645676629...$$

Comment: The form is tantalizing, but still I want to know if there is a particular reason why you are expecting it to have a closed form. Or can you suggest a context where it arises if it have such one?

Comment: If I may ask, in what kind of problem did you find such an integral ?

Comment: I do not have a strong reason to believe it has a closed form, but the integrand looks kinda nice. This integral arises as part of longer calculations related to physics (I wouldn't post them here for several reasons).

Comment: Oh, surely we can always believe that an integral arising naturally in physics either has a close form or defines a nice function...

Comment: According to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/FourSin2.pdf, $\sin x\cdot\operatorname{Ci}x-\cos x\cdot\operatorname{Si}x$ may convert into some improper integrals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplifying Cleo's answer as in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574966/simplification-of-g-2-44-2-left-frac18-frac12-middle-beginarrayc-fr/), we get
$$
\mathcal{S}=-\frac{\pi}{8}\left.\frac{d}{d\nu}L_{\nu}\left(\frac14\right)\right|_{\nu=0}
$$

And a more general result:
$$
\mathcal{S}(a)=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{\sin x\operatorname{Ci}x-\cos x\operatorname{Si}x}{\sqrt{a^{-2}x^2+1}}dx=-\frac{a\pi}{2}\left.\frac{d}{d\nu}L_{\nu}\left(a\right)\right|_{\nu=0}.
$$

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if you consider this a closed form, but the integral $\mathcal{S}$ can be expressed in terms of the generalized Meijer $G$-function (see formula $(3)$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html) for the definition) and [the modified Bessel function of the $2^{nd}$ kind $K_\nu(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html):
$$\mathcal{S}=\frac{G_{2,4}^{4,2}\left(\frac18,\frac12\middle|\begin{array}{c}\frac12,\frac12\\0,0,\frac12,\frac12\\\end{array}\right)}{16\,\pi}-\frac\pi8K_0\left(\frac14\right).$$